# iterating through names by loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I need to do repetitive coding for many years, for instance,

```
G1990 = pd.read_csv("map_1990.csv")
G1991 = pd.read_csv("map_1991.csv")
". . ."
G2015 = pd.read_csv("map_2015.csv")
```

Other examples are,

```
path2001=dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G2001))
path2002=dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G2002))
path2003=dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G2003))
". . . "
path2015=dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G2015))
```

and

```
df2001.to_csv("path2001.csv")
df2002.to_csv("path2002.csv")        
df2003.to_csv("path2003.csv")
". . . "
df2015.to_csv("path2015.csv")
```

it would be nice if I can use a loop to simplify my code, such that

```
for i in range(1990:2015),
    G[i] = pd.read_csv("map_[i].csv")
```

or

```
for i in range(2001:2015),
    path[i]=dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G[i]))
```

and

```
for i in range(1990:2015),
    df[i].to_csv("path[i].csv")
```

Help me please :)

Comment: What exactly you need?

Answer (score 4):

> it would be nice if I can use a loop to simplify my code, such that

```
for i in range(1990:2015),
    G[i] = pd.read_csv("map_[i].csv")
```

[Well now you can!](http://madtv.wikia.com/wiki/Spishak)

You just need to fix the syntax a bit.

- `:` is for slices, not ranges; you need `range(1990, 2015)`.
- Ranges are "half-open", so `range(1990, 2015)` would not include 2015.
- `for` statements, and all compound statements in Python, need a `:` at the end.
- You have to create `G` before you can add things to it.
- Python's format strings use `{}` rather than `[]`.
- Python's format strings have to be explicitly marked with `f`.<sup>1</sup>
- Completely-meaningless single-letter variable names are a bad idea, even in completely-meaningless toy examples; they should instead be words taken from the [Spam sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(Monty_Python)). Otherwise you'll be sentenced to program in C++.

So:

```
eggs = {}
for i in range(1990, 2016):
    eggs[i] = pd.read_csv(f"map_{i}.csv")
```

---

<sub>1. If you're using Python 3.5 or earlier, including 2.7, you can't use f-strings; instead, you have to write `"map_{}.csv".format(i)`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. I guess making it a dictionary is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
g = {}


for i in range(1900,2015):    
        g[i] = pd.read_csv('map_'+ str(i) + '.csv')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah this is another context that I needed a code on. And Robert thanks for pointing that out, but fortunately I was able to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Of course you can do it as follow:

```
G = {}
for i in range(1990, 2016):
    G[i] = pd.read_csv(f"map_{i}.csv")
```

or, in short:

```
G = {i: pd.read_csv(f"map_{i}.csv") for i in range(1990, 2016)}
```